# apt-get: unmet dependencies, but dependencies can't install

Tags: 12.04, apt, upgrade

I'm in a spot where Ubuntu 12.04 LTS wants to do a dist-upgrade, but I can't do anything because /boot is full.

```
~$ df -h
/dev/sda1                               228M  227M     0 100% /boot
```

I want to remove old linux kernels, using `apt-get autoremove`, but I can't, since I have unmet dependencies.

```
~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.9) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.11 is installed
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.9)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

If I try to install the unmet dependencies using `apt-get -f install`, they fail, because /boot is full.

How do I get out of this loop where I can't free space on /boot and `apt-get` won't run?

Comment: Nuke one of the older images in `/boot`. Should free up enough space.

Comment: It appears running `do-release-upgrade` previously while /boot was full screwed up all kinds of things. I manually deleted 2 of the images from `/boot`, but `apt-get` still fails due to a half-installed kernel from the upgrade. Looks like I'll have to do the upgrade again and hope it succeeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to manually free up space in boot. Since `apt-get` was useless, I had to manually remove the files for the 2 oldest linux kernels. This is an example of what I ran to remove a single kernel.

**Warning: Dangerous**:

```
sudo rm /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-36-generic /boot/System.map-3.8.0-36-generic /boot/initrd-3.8.0-36-generic /boot/config-3.8.0-36-generic /boot/abi-3.8.0-36-generic
```

After freeing up space, `apt-get -f install` still failed, due to a half-installed kernel from the previously failed `do-release-upgrade`.

I ran `do-release-upgrade` again, and this time it was successful, *except* for the packages that were previously failing in `apt-get`. Here's an example of what was shown at the end of the upgrade:

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-lts-trusty (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-generic-lts-trusty
 libc6-dev:amd64
 linux-generic-lts-trusty
```

From here, I was able to run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -f install
apt-get autoremove
apt-get upgrade
```

`install` fixed the dependency errors, and `upgrade` installed the latest kernel appropriately. I rebooted to test it out, and everything appears to be good.